# Duplicate and move items

Tags: card-views

I have a long list of items (let's imagine, blog posts or contact cards) that live on a page. Every item has text content, attachments and comments. I want the admin of the page to be able to:

- move an **entire item** to another position
- duplicate **the text content only** of a item to another position

Being the list very long, I'd like to use the concept of "copy and paste":

- the admin **cut** an item and paste it somewhere else in the list (*move*)
- the admin can **copy** an item and paste it somewhere else in the list (*duplicate*)

In this way, I hope to make the interaction more straightforward. However, I need to express the difference between "copy text content only" and "cutting the whole post" (together with attachments and comments)

How would you suggest to express this idea in the interface below? Do you have any other suggestion other than copy and cut that doesn't involve re-rendering my list in a modal?

[image: Example]

Comment: If "Every item has text content, attachments and comments" then why would an admin ever be copying only the text? Could you give an example of when a user would do this?

Comment: Is the goal here to allow a user to create a custom sort order? Or will they be creating actual duplicates of certain items in a list (minus the comments and attachments)? Or will this single page do both? I want you to consider that the method you're proposing might not be the best solution.

Comment: Both, basically they can reorder items and duplicate items (minus comments and attachments).
Yes, I'm aware this might not be the best solution. What I want to avoid is something like "move this item to..." and then let the user decide a position by re-displaying the list in a dialog (like trello does).

The example of a user duplicating a content: I am an admin of this list and I need to create 5 items that have similar content.

Answer (score 1):

I can see three analogies for what you need: drag & drop, the clipboard and the shopping cart.

Drag & drop is used to move or duplicate items (when combined with CTRL key) but is only convenient for short lists, which is not your case.

You're mentioning cut and copy so the clipboard is naturally what comes to mind. It is however invisible and it is not showing whether we are cutting or copying and is it the text content only or the whole item.

The shopping cart seems more appropriate. Have it visible at all times (even when you scroll your list) and show which article it contains (the title first words), whether it includes the comments and attachments (shown by an icon) and the action (cut or copy).

How it works:

- the item is added to the cart by clicking a copy icon on the text content or a cut icon for the whole item
- When the cart is not empty, paste locations appear above and below other items in the list to finish the operation.

You didn't tell if more than one item can be moved or copied at once. The cart allows that: pick several items in the list and move them to a single location.

You can also not empty your cart immediately, allowing to paste the same content 5 times if needed.